# What's the meaning of 'one after the other' in this sentence

Tags: conjunctions

An illness to which man is prone to any age, claimed the one who was **one after the other** abbot, officer, scholar, writer, banker, con artist, magician, infantryman, spy, diplomat, but always claiming his Venetian origins.

I think it equals 'among', am I correct?

Comment: This is giving an interesting twist to merely saying that he claims to be **all** of these. At various times he has claimed to be this and that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*One after the other* or *one after another* means taking each one individually following a sequential order. In this case the author provides a a list of occupations: first he was abbot, then officer, then scholar, and so forth.

*Among* does not imply any order, just one in a grouping, and so is not equivalent here. One could write

> He was, among other things, an abbot, an officer, a scholar, a writer, a banker, a con artist, a magician, an infantryman, a spy, and a diplomat.

and be factually correct but less informative. By this phrasing he could have been a magician first, then later a banker, and then an abbot, and so on.

Comment: Rare but elegant usage of this phrase! Also big thanks for your clearly comparison of the usage here!

Answer (score 1):

"One after the other" as used here (apparently in some [advertising copy](http://www.nagpeople.com/webshop/designers-1/histoires-de-parfums/1725-eau-de-parfum.html)) means [serially](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serially), "In series, one after the other, as opposed to in parallel".

That is, the quotation says that Casanova was in turn an abbot, an officer, a scholar, a writer, a banker, a con artist, a magician, an infantryman, a spy, a diplomat; that is to say, he was an abbot, then an officer, then a scholar, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely , "Among" doesn´t do justice to express the sequel order in which all the individualities take place " one after the other "

Answer (score -2):

No. *Among* is not the intended meaning.

Saying he is *among* followed by a list could mean he is one or more of the descriptions in the list, not necessarily all.

In fact, the implication in this sentence is: ***all*** of them. '*Was one after the other*' is giving an interesting twist to merely saying that he has claimed to be all of these.

Neither is there any significance to the order in the list. '*Was one after the other*' merely implies that at various points of time, he has claimed to be this and claimed to be that.